# Sci-fi short story about neural prosthetics used to simulate a person's brain in an art performance

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, brain-implant

I'm looking for a science fiction short story I read years ago that takes place in the near future where neural prosthetics for people with Alzheimer's, memory loss, and other types of brain damage are common place.

I forget the exact details of the plot, but the final scene of the story involves a piece of performance art where the artist uses multiple prostheses to simulate every part (or as much as is possible) of his brain. He then connects these prostheses to a hologram of sorts that visually simulates his body. This creates a clone of sorts of the artist, that "thinks" that it's a real person. The artist then turns off the components of the simulation one by one, causing the 'clone' to experience a sort of death. At the very end, the artist shoots the machinery powering the simulation with a gun. I recall that in the story, the art performance  is considered illegal since it raises bizarre ethical questions and pushes the boundaries of what neural prostheses can be used for. Does any of this ring a bell for anyone?

The story may have been in one of those annual 'Best Science Fiction of The Year XXXX" anthologies, although I forget the exact name of the anthology. The story also begins with the main character (not the artist) visiting a family member whose hippocampus has been replaced by a machine, so it's unclear where the relative's memories are coming from and whether they are 'authentic'.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: I read this between 2010 and 2018, and I'm guessing it was published after 2000 since my dad bought a lot of sci fi short story anthologies during the aughts and '10s. (e.g. Year's Best SF)